# How to prevent scrolling main section when scrolling sidenav

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In my Angular app I have a sidenav and a main section. The behavior I'm looking for is that while I am scrolling in the sidenav, I don't want any scrolling to be happening in the main section. I want it be behave just like the [Angular Material Design doc site](https://material.angularjs.org/0.11.0/#/api/material.components.dialog/service/$mdDialog).

Currently what is happening is that while scrolling in the sidenav, once I reach the bottom it starts to scroll the main nav.

**Plunker Demo of My Dilemma:**
http://embed.plnkr.co/hyFPXDHCgJqUcJQ6u29i/preview

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: at least for the css part, you may want to add position:fixed to the bar to lock in a static position not affecting the surrounding page

Comment: Thanks PHClaus. I have done that. Check out the plunker demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your external files, presumably the bootstrap stuff. 
After removing all the links and just using the style.css the below was working correctly. Note that I substituted is_right for the right column to test.

```
.list-group {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 70%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.is_right {
    margin-left: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but it didn't work. Here's a plunker with your suggestion: http://embed.plnkr.co/xhO8cAsJvycfcB8gUeRQ/preview

Comment: Not surprised, since you load the same external stuff like before. style.css has nothing of my edit and is_right is missing from the mark-up. Have you actually tried it on a fresh pair of local files without external links? Although scrolling works fine on my end, at least one of the external files gets in the way, in particular if I scale down the screen, right column overlays nav and effectively prevents reaching the scrollbar. Looks like some rather ugly non-responsive CSS somewhere. I've put a demo at http://phclaus.eu.org/css-examples/__temp/